# change value of specified php file by url

Tags: php, url, get

I want to change value of php file by URL request

for example we have this code in log.php file :

```
    <?php
    $my_log = "old.log";
    echo $my_log ;
    ?>
```

and this text will be output :

```
   old.log
```

so i want to call in browser url like this :

```
Http://localhost/log.php?my_log=new.log
```

and i want to get this output :

```
new.log
```

Comment: Use `$_GET['my_log']` to get the URL parameter.

Comment: Watch out when you allow the user to specify a file though. You could easily get a [confused deputy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem) in which the webserver overwrites a file with log content. Assume a malicious actor sends `log.php?my_log=log.php`. That would overwrite your `log.php` file with logging information which would either break your application or be exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$my_log = $_GET['my_log'] ?? 'old.log';
echo $my_log;
?>
```